# Expected to have multiple list value but only get 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

```py
key1= input ("add vertex :")
V = int (key1)
for edge in range (V):
    do=input ("add edge <src><dest><wt>:").split()
    x = [str(do)]
print (x)
```

I try to get a few lists that contain 3 values but why I only got 1? Can you help me?

Comment: because you are overwriting the list over and over again. You need to call append function on list and add the do at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
key1= input ("add vertex :")
V = int (key1)
x = []
for edge in range (V):
    do=input ("add edge <src><dest><wt>:").split()
    x.append(do)
print (x)
```

First create a empty list `x`. Then append `do` in it.

**OUTPUT**

```
add vertex :3
add edge <src><dest><wt>:wiki dekstop 5
add edge <src><dest><wt>:fb program 9
add edge <src><dest><wt>:pintrest users 6
[['wiki', 'dekstop', '5'], ['fb', 'program', '9'], ['pintrest', 'users', '6']]
```

Comment: You don't need to cast `do` to `string`. It is already `string` to begin with.

Comment: Yeah thats what I am also changing .

Comment: yeah. Thanks. It's helpful

Comment: My pleasure. Cheers!